# C# LINQ to Entities - Retrieve all records and position for waiting list records

Tags: c#, linq

I have a waitlist table (id, locationid, timeslotid, sessiondate, memberid, dateAdded) which contains a list of people on various waitlist for various appointments.

I am trying to retrieve a list of all waitlist records for a specific user but i also need to get the position of that record (ordered by dateAdded) so that i can see if they are in position 1, 2, 3 etc in the queue.

The following code is what i have atm for getting all user records, but it am struggling on how to join the count to this query.

```
db.WaitingLists.Where(x => x.MemberId == member.Id && x.LocationId == locationId && x.SessionDate >= currentLocationDate.Date).ToList();
```

Some suggestions would be welcomed on how to do this.

Thanks

============= UPDATE ==============

This is the SQL that provides the response I need.  I am trying to prevent using a stored Proc and try and use linq to entities where possible.

```
select 
(
SELECT count(*) RowNr
            FROM (
                SELECT 
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CreatedDate) AS RowNr,
                     MemberId
                FROM waitinglist where LocationId = wl.LocationId and TimeSlotId = wl.TimeSlotId and [SessionDate] = wl.SessionDate
            ) sub
)
as Position, * from WaitingList as wl where memberid = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

Comment: *ordered by dateAdded* so, where is your  `OrderBy(...)` method call? what is the question? how ordering is connected with "join count" ?

Comment: OK, I'm a little confused by your SQL. It looks like it will give you (for `Position`) the number of records in the waiting list for the same location, time slot, and session date, along with every record in `WaitingList` that has the desired member ID. The `Position` value won't have anything to do with the record's `CreatedDate`, because in your subquery you're just doing a `count(*)` on the records from `sub`, and not using the `sub.RowNr` value.

Comment: Based on that query, your `Position` value would be more accurately titled `MatchingLocationTimeAndSessionTotalRecords`.

Comment: If that's actually what you want, I may be able to come up with LINQ to do that for you, but I'm wondering if that's REALLY what you want!

Comment: (Clarifying: I'm doubting this is what you want because your `Position` calculation has nothing to do with what order among the matching location/time/session records a given record falls. It's just a count of all the records in that queue!)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it should be pretty close. Filter first by the location and date, then sort it, then use the [overload of `Select` that gives you an index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__), then filter by the member ID.

```
db.WaitingLists
    .Where(x => x.Member.LocationId == locationId && x.Member.SessionDate >= currentLocationDate.Date)
    .OrderBy(x => x.DateAdded)
    .Select((x, i) => new { Position = i, Member = x })
    .Where(x => x.Member.MemberId == member.Id)
    .ToList();
```

This will give you a list of anonymous objects with two properties:

- `Position`, which is the position in the waiting list, and
- `Member`, which is the member details

I can't say what the SQL will actually look like, and if it will be efficient.

Comment: Thank you for this...

I am getting an error - LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType15`2[System.Int32,Data.WaitingList]]

Comment: On which part? The `Select`? You may need to move the `ToList()` to before `Select()`. That means you will be querying the database for the entire queue, and then discarding some of the results. Not ideal, but if the queue is usually short, it'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you. I'm assuming that the queue position is across all locations and session dates.  If it isn't, insert another `Where` clause in between `db.WaitingLists` and the `OrderBy`.

```
var temp = db.WaitingLists
   .Orderby(x => x.dateAdded)
   .Select( (r, i) => new { Request = r, QueuePosition = i + 1)
   .Where(x => x.Request.MemberId == member.Id && 
               x.Request.LocationId == locationId && 
               x.Request.SessionDate >= currentLocationDate.Date);
```

You now have a list of anonymous-type objects that have the **Request** (my name for your type; rename it if you want to) and a second property called **QueuePosition**, based on the position of the requests in the queue, as represented by the **WaitingList** sorted by **dateAdded**.

If you need to extract just the **Request** object, you can get it this way:

```
var selectedRequests = temp.Select(x => x.Request).ToList();
```

If you want to get any entries that were in the first 3 positions, you'd do this:

```
var selectedRequests = temp.Where(x => x.QueuePosition <= 3).Select(x => x.Request).ToList();
```

Disclaimer: done from memory, not actually tested.

Comment: So a user can be on multiple waitlist..wait lists are based on combination of SessionDate + LocationId + TimeslotId.  The memberID query is simply so that i can only get the records that are relevant to that user (it is their booking display)

Comment: Also..if that's from memory..you rock ;)  Trying now!

Comment: Why, thank you! You may well get the same error you did with Gabriel's answer. (That's why I included the disclaimer that I hadn't tested it!)

Comment: Similar to Gabriel i am getting a count of all the records rather than grouped by the ones that the member is within...The SQL that returns me the correct answer has been added above..